ValueError:Unable to create tensor,Perhaps your features (`text`) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected)
I'm working on fine-tuning mbart-large-50 and i keep getting the same error no matter what i did
tokenize method
# Pre-trained tokenizer
tokenizer = MBart50TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-50", src_lang="ar_AR", tgt_lang="en_XX")

# Tokenize function
def tokenize_function(examples):
     tokenized_output=tokenizer(examples["text"], padding=True, truncation=True)
     return {'input_ids':tokenized_output['input_ids'], 'attention_mask':tokenized_output['attention_mask']}

# Tokenize ENdataset
EN_tokenized = ENdataset_1000.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
EN_df = pd.DataFrame(EN_tokenized)

# Tokenize ARdataset
AR_tokenized = ARdataset_1000.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
AR_df = pd.DataFrame(AR_tokenized)

# Add language labels
EN_df["language"] = "en"
AR_df["language"] = "ar"

# Concatenate DataFrames
df = pd.concat([EN_df, AR_df], ignore_index=True)

training method

# Fine-tuned mBART model

API_URL = "facebook/mbart-large-50"

# Define training arguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
"output_dir",
learning_rate=2e-5,
num_train_epochs=3,
logging_dir="logs",
logging_steps=100,
load_best_model_at_end=True,
remove_unused_columns=False,
evaluation_strategy="epoch",
save_strategy="epoch",
save_total_limit=3,
)

# Instantiate the mBART model

model = MBartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(API_URL)

# Define the Trainer object

trainer = Trainer(
tokenizer=tokenizer,
model=model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=train_ds,
)
trainer.train()

and the full error was
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`text` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected).

i tried to change the tokenization function but unfortunately i have limited skills yet

Read this and then see if you can resolve it: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/pad_truncation
